# API_Multiple users

Tags: javascript, html, api

**I need to make a table with 6 random users using html. I only get one user data !
what should i do ? do i have to make a loop ?

this is the code i useed **
i tried to change the id but there was no output.
please let me know what approach i shall follow.
`

```
<body>

    <h2>API</h2>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Full Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </thead>
    
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td id="fullname"></td>
    <td id="age"></td>
    <td id="gender"></td>
    <td id="location"></td>
    <td id="counrty"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="fullname"></td>
    <td id="age"></td>
    <td id="gender"></td>
    <td id="location"></td>
    <td id="counrty"></td>
  </tr>

  </table>

 
<script>
    const api_url="https://randomuser.me/api/";
  
    async function getUser() {
        const response= await  fetch(api_url);
        const data= await response.json();

        const user=data.results[0];
        let{first, last} = user.name;
        let{gender, email, phone} = user;
        let age = user.dob.age;
        let{city, state, country} = user.location;
        let fullName = first + " " + last;

        document.querySelector("#fullname").textContent = fullName;
        document.querySelector("#age").textContent = age;
        document.querySelector("#gender").textContent = gender;
        document.querySelector("#location").textContent = city + " ," + state;
        document.querySelector("#counrty").textContent= country;
      }
        getUser();
    
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

`
**what shall i do to take more random users ?
shall i create more ids?**

Comment: Don't use multiple same `ids`  instead create the `<tr>` structure directly in js with some data-attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you when using any other people's code (api/framework etc.) to go and look at the [documentation](https://randomuser.me/documentation#howto).
As you can see from my code below, you can specify how many users you want as return from the api and do a simple `forEach` to insert them into the table.

```js
const userNumber = 6;
const api_url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=" + userNumber; //change number base to your need.
async function getUser() {
  const response = await fetch(api_url);
  const data = await response.json();
  data.results.forEach(user => {
    let {
      first,
      last
    } = user.name;
    let {
      gender,
      email,
      phone
    } = user;
    let age = user.dob.age;
    let {
      city,
      state,
      country
    } = user.location;
    let fullName = first + " " + last;
    document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML +=
      `<tr>
       <td data-fullname>${fullName}</td>
       <td data-age>${age}</td>
       <td data-gender>${gender}</td>
       <td data-location>${city} , ${state}</td>
       <td data-country>${country}</td>
   </tr>`;
  });
}

getUser();
```

```html
<h2>API</h2>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>Full Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody></tbody>

</table>
```

Remember instead that the ID of the elements **must** be unique